# orderBy is not working, when i formatted the content in the html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in PackagesData | orderBy : filterOption">
<td>{{data.name}}</td>
<td>{{data.packageType}}</td>
<td>{{convertDateFormatNormal(data.createdDate)}}</td>
</tr>

$scope.convertDateFormatNormal = function (date) {
        if(date){
            var dateFormatChange = new Date(date);
            var dateChanged = $filter('date')(dateFormatChange, "dd/MM/yyyy");
            return dateChanged;
        }
    };
```

filterOption in orderBy can be anything name, packageType or createdDate. But name and package type working as expected but orderBy not working for createdDate since i converted the date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy to display in HTML, still it sorts only in mm/dd/yyyy order.

Comment: This was good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular js, sorting is depend on the format of scope variable, not on the printed format in html. If you want to sort it using dd/mm/yyyy format, you have to format the date in your js file & store it in a key like 'modified_date' by loop through the 'PackagesData' object & then type {{modified_date}} in html & filter it by 'modified_date'.
Once I faced the same issue but I sorted out in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This sample based on `orderBy` and focused on order by full date which if we have `array` like this:

```
[
  { createdDate: "2007-04-01T14:30" },
  { createdDate: "2006-01-05T14:30" },
  { createdDate: "2018-06-06T14:30" },
  { createdDate: "2015-03-08T14:30" },
  { createdDate: "2010-02-11T14:30" },
  { createdDate: "2010-01-12T14:30" }
];
```

the order should be `yyyy` and then `MM` at last `dd`, by this description we have to create custom function which convert our dates to the one row for example:

> If we have `05/01/2006 => "dd/MM/yyyy"`it should be `20060105 => "yyyyMMdd`

**remeber** result should be `int` not `string`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "$filter", function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.array = [{
      name: "John",
      packageType: 1,
      createdDate: "2007-04-01T14:30"
    },
    {
      name: "Mike",
      packageType: 2,
      createdDate: "2006-01-05T14:30"
    },
    {
      name: "Mike",
      packageType: 2,
      createdDate: "2018-06-06T14:30"
    },
    {
      name: "Mike",
      packageType: 2,
      createdDate: "2015-03-08T14:30"
    },
    {
      name: "Mike",
      packageType: 2,
      createdDate: "2010-02-11T14:30"
    },
    {
      name: "Mike",
      packageType: 2,
      createdDate: "2010-01-12T14:30"
    }
  ];

  $scope.orderByFullDate = function(object) {
    var x = object.createdDate.split('/');
    var y = "";
    if (angular.isDefined(x[1])) {
      y = x[2] + x[1] + x[0];
    }
    return parseInt(y); //result of '05/01/2006' is: 20060105
  };

  $scope.convertDateFormatNormal = function(object) {
    if (object) {
      var dateFormatChange = new Date(object.createdDate);
      var dateChanged = $filter('date')(dateFormatChange, "dd/MM/yyyy");
      object.createdDate = dateChanged;
    }
  };


}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="object in array | orderBy:orderByFullDate" ng-init="convertDateFormatNormal(object)">
      {{object.createdDate}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```